# Best data type for list of <ID, object>?

Tags: c#, performance

What's the best data type *performance-wise* for a list of tuples composed of `<ID, object>`, such that the IDs are not unique?

For example:

```
1 tire
1 rim
1 spoke
2 buckle
2 flap
2 bag
```

What would give the best performance when selecting for `ID = 1`?  I have over a million rows.

Comment: They're not *IDs* per se, since they don't *identify* the object, they're just integers.  Any list would likely have the same performance.  A list of Tuples, a list of custom objects, etc.

Comment: `List<Tuple<int,object>> ` or `List<KeyValuePair<int, object>>`

Comment: @David Presently using a list of tuples.  I thought maybe some multi-key hash structure may exist.

Comment: If you are OK with a read-only data structure, once all items are known, then LINQ's [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460184(v=vs.100).aspx) might be of interest. You can turn any collection into a [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) using LINQ's `.ToLookup(…)` operator. For example, you could turn a mutable `List<Tuple<int,string>>` (where look-up by "ID" would be linear-time) into an immutable `Lookup<int,Tuple<int,string>>` or `Lookup<int,string>` (where lookup by "ID" would be constant-time).

Comment: How are you going to search?   Search on a specific object or you want a return a collection of objects for the ID?

Comment: @Blam Returning a collection by ID

Comment: @ryanyuyu What are the performance benefits of that?

Comment: Then the answer from GlorFindel but it too bad there is not more explanation

Comment: @ryanyuyu Fair enough.  I rolled back to your revision.

Comment: @Daniel no worries.  Happy to help.  Sorry I didn't have an actual answer for your question.  (BTW, I'm removing some of my obsolete comments).

Comment: Daniel rather spar over comments get on with the answer.  You have  a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for `Dictionary<int, List<object>>`, this guarantees a fast lookup when selecting by ID. Dictionary keys have to be unique, but the `List` allows you to put more than one object under the same key.

Comment: *Well,* the key is not unique in the data above, ....never mind...I  just saw `List<object>`, you might clarify that a bit more in your answer.

Comment: This would require first finding the item in the dictionary, then appending to the list when you want to add items, so there's a tradeoff.

Comment: @AngularRat OP specially asked for best performance when selecting and this is the best answer

Comment: @Daniel And it would be in this situation.

Comment: Yes, it does. I have edited my answer  - @Habib hinted at this as well.

Comment: How would you change it for a list like the following, would it still apply? I noticed this is very similar to a question I was about to ask. I'm trying to find ip addresses depending on the fruit type associated with them. The fruits will repeat, the address + port won't, and I'd like to find local addresses first: {'apple' -> '128.0.0.1:2012', 'carrot' -> '128.0.0.2:2032', 'apple' -> '12.1.0.1:1325', 'banana' -> '121.111.111.2:2203', 'orange' -> '50.220.220.10:2240', 'carrot' -> '113.211.10.5:2012', 'carrot' -> '128.0.0.1:2011', 'banana' -> '128.0.0.1:2014', 'banana' -> '113.211.10.5:1204'}

Comment: In that case, I'd go for two dictionaries, one with local addresses and one with global addresses.

Comment: Wouldn't the extra "lookups" cost significant speed? At worst case, it's more than four lookups. 1) Check local dictionary for addresses matching the right fruit, 2) check corresponding list for ip addresses, say none work. 3) Check global dictionary for addresses matching the right fruit, 4) check corresponding list for ip addresses, 5...) continue checking list until one works. Is there a way to avoid this performance hit?

Comment: Lookup for these kind of things is negligible (less than 1 microsecond) compared to to the cost of any network communication (usually more than 10 milliseconds).

Comment: Now what difference does it make if there are only 100 different types of fruit, and maybe hundreds of thousands or millions of ip+port pairs? Thus the performance-heavy part is the list, and not the dictionary?

Comment: Also, what about in C++?

Answer (score 1):

See the answer from Glorfindel
Contains and Lookup by Key is O(1) (or near) so this is going to be the best speed

```
private Dictionary<int, List<object>> dl = new Dictionary<int, List<object>>();
private void AddDL(Int id, Object obj)
{
    if(dl.ContainsKey(id))
       dl[id].Add(obj);
    else 
       dl.Add(id, new List<Object>{obj});
}
```

Since Int has no hash collisions I think lookup will be 0(1)

```
List<Object> myObjs = dl[id];
```

If you create with an initial capacity > count then even dl.Add is O(1)
So if you have over 1 million unique ID then

```
private Dictionary<int, List<object>> dl = new Dictionary<int, List<object>>(1000000);
```

Same thing with List so may want to start with a capacity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> stuff = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

        // Populate list with some stuff
        stuff.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Asdf"));
        stuff.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "wqer"));
        stuff.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "fghj"));
        stuff.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "vnbm"));
        stuff.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Asdf"));

        // Use linq to get items with certain key
        var results = stuff.Where(x => x.Key == 1).ToList();
```

I can't guarantee that's the fastest possible way...you could use a sorted list and possibly save a little processor time combing through results.  But for most applications, this will work fine because the List and other container classes are relatively efficient.